# Obtaining both an Analog and Digital 5V Supply From Single 5V Supply

Tags: power-supply

I'm replacing a stolen PCM4222EVM adc with a PCM4202EVM adc but they left my  + -15V, 5V triple-output linear power supply.  However, I just discovered that there is a difference in powering the PCM4202EVM in that it also requires an extra DIGITAL 5V supply, so 4 separate power supplies: + - 15V, 5V & 5V Digital.

Being a dolt, can I just solder a wire to my 5V supply and run it to the digital header or do I need to do some kind of decoupling with a capacitor setup? Also, what would I do with the grounds?

I may replace the triple-linear with a triple-switching supply if that makes any difference with adding the 5V digital.  Both would supply adequate current for the dual 5V draw btw.

Comment: What does the EVM manual say how to connect it?

Comment: Since it doesn't sound like you're too worried about efficiency, and the datasheet calls for a maximum of 200mA at 5v, I would consider just sticking two linear 5v regulators on the +15 rail and generating independently regulated +5v supplies so that you didn't need a three rail power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ground connection of +15/-15 and +5 supply would be a concern.
[image: partial schematic PCM4202EVM]
The two **analog gnd** and **digital gnd** are connected on the EVM board. I would want the digital supply to be independent of the analog supply, so that their grounds connect at only one spot: on the EVM board.

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies.  It appears that I should add a separate 5V power supply to my triple-output supply case, and since I used an umbilical cable with a couple of unused wires from it to the converter I was thinking of just repurposing a 5V phone charger that has at least half an amp per spec requirements, and it would be invisible and look clean.  Is there an issue with using a phone charger for my digital 5V supply?